# Hiding a System.Random instance by returning a function

Tags: .net-core, f#

The following code comes from *Stylish F# 6: Crafting Elegant Functional Code for .NET 6* listing 9-13:

```
let randomByte =
    let r = System.Random()
    fun () ->
        r.Next(0, 255) |> byte
// E.g. A3-52-31-D2-90-E6-6F-45-1C-3F-F2-9B-7F-58-34-44-
for _ in 0..15 do
    printf "%X-" (randomByte())
printfn ""
```

The author states, "Although we call randomByte() multiple times, only one System.Random() instance is created."

I understand randomByte returns a function that does not create a System.Random() instance, but it seems to me multiple System.Random() instances would be created each time through the for-do-loop anyway.

I would appreciate an explanation of how multiple instances of System.Random() are not created in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that `randomByte` is *not a function*. It's a value with some complex initialization logic. Like, for example, I could write:

```
let x = 5
```

Or I could write:

```
let x =
  let fourtyTwo = 42
  let thirtySeven = 37
  fourtyTwo - thirtySeven
```

And these would be equivalent. Both declare a value named `x` and equal to `5`. I hope you can see how the expression `fourtyTwo - thirtySeven` is evaluated only once, not every time somebody gets the value of `x`.

And so it works with `randomByte` too: it's a value with non-trivial initialization logic. During that value's initialization, first it creates an instance of `System.Random`, and then it creates an anonymous function that closes over that instance, and this anonymous function becomes the value of `randomByte`.